# Angular ionic ui-router, the same child view for other parents

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

It may be hard to explain but i will try:
Im using ionic framework and ui-router in my app and have following situation:

```
.state('tab.promoAward', {
           url: "/promoAward/:id",
           views: {
                'tab-search': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/customer/promoAward.html',
                    controller: 'promoAwardCtrl',
                },
                'tab-favourites': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/customer/promoAward.html',
                    controller: 'promoAwardCtrl',
                },
            },
        })
```

As you can see, i want display the same child view (awards) for other parent tabs (search, and favourites). Above example working but if i am on tab-search state when call promoAwardCtrl then application automatilcy going to tab-favourites (i want stay in tab-seach state) state and I losing "back button" (to prevoius state).

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

/****************EDIT*****************/

Solution is:

```
.state('tab.promoAward', {
              url: '/promoAward/:id',
            views: { 
                '':{
                },
                'tab-search@tab': {
                    controller: 'promoAwardCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/customer/promoAward.html'
                },
                'tab-favourites@tab': {
                    controller: 'promoAwardCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/customer/promoAward.html'
                },
            },
        })
```

Thanks for all replies

Comment: Can you post the markup of the element that you're clicking to trigger the state change? Are you using ui-sref in an anchor tag?

Comment: Hi Jim, no i don't use ui-sref, this is done in some way "internally" in ionic library, but i found the solution already (will write the solution in by editing my post)

Comment: The suggested solution raises issues when both parents try to show different awards in parallel (the states are not truly independent).

Comment: thanks! Using ionic framework as well and was facing the same problem.

Comment: Trying to achive the same thing, This doesn't work for me. Is there a reason you have ' ' : {}   (which is mapping an empty string to an empty object) and then commands after the '}' on the second last and third last lines?

Comment: solution works partially for me. I am not getting back button. Is there any workaround for that ?

Answer (score 0):

cannot be done, see this post in the ionic forums http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/creating-shared-routes-in-different-views/3955

Answer (score 0):

In angular ui routing I used multiple child views for same parent. but not sure its possible in your case. One suggestion is put  **parent:"name of parent"** in child views might work.

Comment: Actually i have no experience in ui-router, but resolved this problem as in the first post (edited part)